# Need help with an Apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have a junction object with two master detail relationships. One to contacts and one to a custom object named program. I created the following trigger to avoid duplicates but im having A LOT of trouble with the testing part. Can someone tell me what could the test code for this trigger be? Thank you

```
trigger insert_case on Affiliated_Programs__c (before insert, before update) {
  for (Affiliated_Programs__c ci : trigger.new) {

//Checks the database for all affiliated programs with the same program and contact
  List<Affiliated_Programs__c> resultList = [SELECT id, Name FROM Affiliated_Programs__c
  WHERE Contact__c = :ci.Contact__c
  AND Program__c = :ci.Program__c];

// Raise the error back if any records found
   if (!resultList.isEmpty()) {
      System.debug('Found another copy ' + resultList[0].id + ' name is ' + resultList[0].Name);
      ci.addError('Duplicate record, a Contact is already related to that program');
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Here your have a workaround to unique junction objects without code at all: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/12756/636

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply uniqueness on Junction object?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-apply-uniqueness-on-junction-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Notice that you could solve the junction unique **avoiding apex code*** [using this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/12756/636)

Having say that, this is a *trivial* example of how could be your trigger test:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class basicTests{

    @isTest static void runTests(){
        system.debug('starting tests...');
        test.startTest();     

        A__c a = new A__c(Name='test-trigger-a');
        B__c b = new B__c(Name='test-trigger-b');

        C__c c = new C__c(Name='test-trigger-c',ChildOfB__c = b.id,ChildOfA__c = a.id);
        C__c c2 = new C__c(Name='test-trigger-c2',ChildOfB__c = b.id,ChildOfA__c = a.id);
        try{
            insert c;
            insert c2;
            //fail!
            System.assert(false);
        }catch(System.DmlException e){
            System.assert(true);
        }

        test.stopTest();

    }    

}
```

Comment: Thank you martin for both suggestions. Both worked and I got a better understanding of trigger tests!

Answer (score 0):

If by avoiding duplicates, you mean no two junction objects can have the same two parents, then you should try searching across the stack: [How to apply uniqueness on Junction object?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-apply-uniqueness-on-junction-object/12774?noredirect=1#comment18303_12774)

Comment: Because I was using an apex trigger and I wanted to learn how test methods work. Thank you for your contribution.